# Randomly generate points in an Image in a selected ROI. (Image J macro)

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

I am trying to put n dots randomly on a selected ROI in an image using the macro;

```
Roi.getBounds(x,y,w,h);
count = 0;
while (count < n) { 
    roiManager( "select", 0 ); // select the first, "big" ROI
    x1 = random() * w + x;
    y1 = random() * h + y;
    if (selectionContains(x1, y1) == true ) { // if coordinates are inside the "big" ROI 
        makePoint(x1, y1); // generate random point
        roiManager("Add");// add the point to the ROI Manager
        count++; // ONLY increase count when point is added
    }
}
```

But now, I want a condition that I should not get (x,y) in a (x-1,y-1), (x+1,y+1) neighbourhood. How can I write ths in the code? (no 2 points should be closer by 1 pixel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a function, that calculates the distance between your new point and all of your existing point (it actually calculates the square of the distance, but it doesn't really matter). Function returns `true` if the two points are neighbours and `false` if they are not.

```
Roi.getBounds(x,y,w,h);
count = 0;
n=3;
allx=newArray(n);  // creates array where all of the points will be stored
ally=newArray(n);  // creates array where all of the points will be stored

// function that calculates distance between all of the selected points
function is_neighbour(array_x, array_y, x1, y1){
    for (elem=0; elem<array_x.length; elem++){
        x2 = array_x[elem];
        y2 = array_y[elem];
        distance = (x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2);
        if (distance < 3) return true;
        }
    return false;
    }

while (count < n) { 
    roiManager( "select", 0 ); // select the first, "big" ROI
    x1 = random() * w + x;
    y1 = random() * h + y;
    if (selectionContains(x1, y1) == true ) { // if coordinates are inside the "big" ROI 
        if ( !is_neighbour(allx, ally, x1, y1 ) ){
            makePoint(x1, y1); // generate random point
            roiManager("Add"); // add the point to the ROI Manager
            allx[count] = x1; // add x1 to array of all x
            ally[count] = y1; // add y1 to array of all y
            count++; // ONLY increase count when point is added
        }         
    }
```

Something in your code doesn't work for me, so I couldn't really test it. But the `is_neighbour` function works.
Oh and I defined neighbour as all of the points that are in contact (even diagonally):
[image: neighbours]

If you are only interested in the light read ones, just change `distance < 2` .

Comment: thank you very much! I got the idea, I will test this .